# Accessing the Static member

Tags: c

I have declared the one static member inside the static method. like as follws:

```
   static void temp1(param..){
        static gint x,y ;

        #TODO what you needed

        values get changed here for x,y;
   }
```

And I want to access this Two in other static method within the same file.

```
  static void temp2 ( param .......){
         accessing the x,y
  }
```

How should I do it..? I don't want to declare public member and also don't want to change the method param's .

Comment: With those constraints, I don't think it's possible. I'd be interested to see if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't really do this without globals or function arguments.

Comment: it is not irrelevant, e.g. could use messaging

Comment: @claptrap "without changing function arguments..."

Comment: yes exactly, PostMessage()

Comment: Scene is I have the structure instance but if I add this two x,y in struct then instance is always get created in method for e.g temp1 and value always set to 0. that I don't want. values which gets changed in the temp2 for the second time should be always used in temp1 until the program exit.

Comment: you are confusing lifetime with scope. 'x' and 'y' are local variables in function temp1() [(scope limited to temp1()]

Comment: There are no "members" or "methods" in C.

Comment: anyway sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might almost be what you want:

```
static gint x,y ;

static void temp1(param..){

  /* TODO what you needed */

  values get changed here for x,y;
}

static void temp2 ( param .......){
  /* accessing the x,y */
}
```

x and y are globally accessible, *but only within the file,* just like your static procedures. I think this is as close as you can get to what you want.

Comment: this isn't what the OP want.

Comment: Even if you are not exporting the x & y variables, they are still, _technically_ public within the file.For all we know, there could be another x & y defined globally to do something else and this suggestion would mess that up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand these 2 things:

```
Scope
```

and

```
Lifetime
```

the scope of your static variables is only `inside the function they are declared`. they cannot be accessed outside.

but the `lifetime of your variables is throughout your program`, that is they will retain the values until the program is running.

So maybe you would like to declare your variables outside of your function. so instead of

```
static void temp1(param..){
        static gint x,y ;

        #TODO what you needed

        values get changed here for x,y;
   }
```

you can have

```
 static gint x,y ;
static void temp1(param..){
               #TODO what you needed

        values get changed here for x,y;
   }
```

The exact use case you have, i think it would not be possible without changing the second function's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int getInnerStatic(int* _x, int* _y, int ignore);

static void temp1(param..){
    static int x,y ;

    ////////////////
    if (getInnerStatic(&x,&y,1))
        return;
    ////////////////

    #TODO what you needed

    values get changed here for x,y;
}



static int getInnerStatic(int* _x, int* _y, int ignore){
    static int innerInvok = 0;
    static int x, y;

    if (innerInvok == 1){
        x = *_x;
        y = *_y;
        return innerInvok;//1
    }

    if (ignore)
        return innerInvok;//0

    innerInvok = 1;
    temp1(/*anything as param...*/);
    innerInvok = 0;

    *_x = x;
    *_y = y;

    return innerInvok;//0
}

//get static x y :
static void temp2 ( param .......){
    int getX, getY;

    getInnerStatic(&getX, &getY, 0); // <- accessing the x,y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static void temp1() {
    static int x,y ;
    x = 5;
    y = 8;
}

static void temp2 (){
    cout << temp1::x << endl;
}

int main() {
    temp2()
    return 0;
}
```

**Error message**

```
error: ‘temp1’ is not a class or namespace
```

Note the error that occurs when you try to access x in temp1 by using the scope resolution operator `::`. Here is how to solve this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace temp {
    class temp1 {
    public:
        static int x,y;
    };
    int temp1::x = 5;
    int temp1::y = 7;
}

static void temp2 (){
    cout << temp::temp1::x << endl;
}

int main() {
    temp2();
    return 0;
}
```

Note the namespace is not necessary, but I used it to keep related data together

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with your existing code you need to modify your code to make x and y as static instance variables so that you can access them in all the static methods.